# Why does my whole screen disappear when I set one div to display:none?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am required to make this control go away under certain circumstances. Here is my code:

```
    var blade = document.getElementById("blade");
        if (!this.showBlade) {
            blade.style.display = "none";
        }
```

this is the code for the control:

```
    <div id="blade" class="immersive-flex-pane-right">

        <dpn-blade-carousel on-init="$page.onBladesInit($component)"
                            starting-blade="gc-choose-community-blade"
                            params="{ dom: $page.dom }"
                            class="blades" />

    </div>
```

Why is my whole screen now blank?

Comment: Check with this blade.style.visibility= "collapse";

Comment: There may be another element with name of "blade" which covers all screen?